# Automatically rename Excel column header before copying through SSIS Script task

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to rename certain excel column header before copying/removing file to new destination through SSIS Script Task and File System Task, but unable to do so. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: It should be possible with a Script task.   What error are you getting when trying?   Please add your Script code to your question.

Comment: I'm trying to reuse the codes from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340560/how-to-automate-renaming-of-column-headers-in-excel-2013-worksheets-using-c-shar#
. But no idea how will it work, still researching for better approach. initially I'm getting an error with the dll Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel